# International characters stripped when set via global_merge_vars

Tags: parse-platform, mandrill

Given the following Mandrill e-mail template identified by `sample-template`:

```
Hi *|FIRST_NAME|*,

Here are some international characters: ąćę.
```

and `sendTemplate` call executed using Mandrill's Parse SDK:

```
Mandrill.sendTemplate({
    template_name: 'sample-template',
    template_content: {},
    message: {
        subject: 'This e-mail will have some characters missing',
        to: [{
            email: 'dummy@example.com',
            type: 'to',
        }],
        global_merge_vars: [{
            name: 'FIRST_NAME',
            content: 'Jędrzej',
        }],
    },
    async: true,
}, {
    success: function(httpResponse) {},
    error: function(httpResponse) {},
});
```

will result in the following e-mail to be delivered to recipient (as viewed in an e-mail client):

```
Hi Jdrzej,

Here are some international characters: ąćę.
```

Notice that the international character `ę` in the name `Jędrzej` is missing, giving `Jdrzej` on the first line. This does *not* happen when international characters are placed directly in the template, but only if they are provided via `global_merge_vars`.

Inspection of the raw message revealed that the `ąćę` characters where properly escaped in the body of the message:

```
Hi Jdrzej,

Here are some international characters: =C4=85=C4=87=C4=99.
```

as per e-mail headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

It looks like Mandrill API simply strips non-ASCII characters from merge values before applying them to a template.

What's the correct way of supporting international (UTF-8) characters in merge tags?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it is an issue with Mandrill Cloud Code module provided by Parse. Check out comments below the first post: https://parse.com/questions/sometimes-getting-mandrill-you-must-specify-a-key-value-error-when-sending-email.

To work around this bug, simply call Mandrill's API directly:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    },
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json',
    body: {
        key: MANDRILL_API_KEY,
        template_name: 'sample-template',
        template_content: {},
        message: {
            subject: 'This e-mail will will display correctly',
            to: [{
                email: 'dummy@example.com',
                type: 'to',
            }],
            global_merge_vars: [{
                name: 'FIRST_NAME',
                content: 'Jędrzej',
            }],
        },
        async: true,
    },
    success: function(httpResponse) {},
    error: function(httpResponse) {},
});
```